# dynamicly change properties"DefaultMessageListenerContainer.concurrentConsumers" in Spring JMS with JMX

Tags: java, spring

i m going to be crazy ! i can't figure out what's wrong with it .please help!

i want to  set concurrentConsumers in Spring JMS dynamicly. the following is my code :

```
<bean id="syncHotProductPool" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="2" />
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="syncHotProductExecutor-" />
        <property name="daemon" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="syncHotProductListener" class="com.ngsp.zrb.messageContainer.DynamicMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsSyncProductFactory" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="2" />
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="2" />
        <property name="destination" ref="syncHotProductQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="syncHotProductReceiver" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="syncHotProductPool" />
        <!--0:CACHE_NONE,1:CACHE_CONNECTION,2:CACHE_SESSION,3:CACHE_CONSUMER,4:CACHE_AUTO-->
        <property name="cacheLevel" value="3" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

@JmxSource(objectName = "com.ngsp.zrb.common.messageContainer:type=messageContainer")
public class DynamicMessageListenerContainer extends DefaultMessageListenerContainer {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicMessageListenerContainer.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@JmxAttribute
private String destinationName;

public String getDestinationName() {
    Destination destination = super.getDestination();
    if (destination instanceof Queue) {
        Queue queue = (Queue) destination;
        try {
            return queue.getQueueName();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@JmxOperation
public final void dynamicStop() throws JMSException {
    doStop();
}

@JmxOperation
public final void dynamicStart() throws JMSException {
    doStart();
}

@JmxOperation
public final void setConcurrentConsumersNum(int i) throws JMSException {

    setIdleConsumerLimit(i);

    setConcurrentConsumers(i);


}

@JmxOperation
public final int getConcurrentConsumersNum() throws JMSException {
    return getConcurrentConsumers();

}
```

}

then i start my tomcat ,and  set ConcurrentConsumers  from 1(default) to 8.it's ok!but ,when i set  ConcurrentConsumers  from  8 to 1.the queue stop comsume message! why ???